# CC1101 not always working

Tags: wireless

Our project has one CC1101 transmitter sending signals to several CC1101 receivers. The transmitter sends signal to the first receiver, waits a couple of seconds before sending signal to second receiver, waits another couple of seconds before signalling to third receiver, and so on. After a while it then re-starts the signalling sequence.

The problem we have is that sometimes the signal is not received by a receiver as expected, this happens more as the distance is increased. The distances are not very long, but all boards are very close to the ground.

The problem isn't that a signal is never received, which would be easy to accept, but rather that it is sometimes not received. The same receiver gets a signal one time but not another time. Similarly, one receiver may not get a signal but the next one does.

Any pointers on what the problem could be?  Is this likely to be poor hardware design or incorrect firmware settings?

Thanks

Comment: *Is this likely to be poor hardware design...* I hope you mean **your** hardware and not the CC1101. Did you follow all the suggestions in the datasheet? *or incorrect firmware settings?* The CC1101 has lots of settings and some influence its range. If you **lower the datarate** and choose a simpler (more robust) type of modulation the range might increase. Some understanding of how wireless data comms works is required!

Comment: I definitely meant our own hardware design. It does follow the guidelines and certainly works, just not as well as hoped for. Some firmware updates improved performance, but the range is well below TI estimate (using their spreadsheet). We're using GFSK with 1.2kBaud data rate. Measured dBm is close to the 10dBm limit.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem we have is that sometimes the signal is not received by a receiver as expected, this happens more as the distance is increased.

Yes. That's wireless communications for you: the further you go away, the less power you receive, the more multipath you might see, and thus, the worse your SNR gets.

Noise introduces errors. Deal with it!

> The distances are not very long

"not very long" is err... not a specification? is "not very long" 10 cm? 100m? 10 km?

> Any pointers on what the problem could be? Is this likely to be poor hardware design or incorrect firmware settings?

Well, something close to ground will not have a free Fresnel zone between a receiver and a transmitter, so little power can be received, even with good design and good antennas.

I'd bet on a combination of inappropriate design, antennas and this natural limitation. Also, you might not be picking a sufficiently robust mode.

My best guess is that if putting your transmitter up high solves your problem, you're simply in a situation where propagation conditions due to the close ground are too bad.

Comment: By not very long, I mean no more than 25-30 metres. Why does a signal get through some of the time, not all of the time? Sometimes a restart of the board ensures signal gets through. Just wondering whether some registers are not being cleared/flushed properly.

Comment: The channel is time variant, and noise is random. The assumption "if it works once, it always works" simply doesn't apply.